# Large Numpy array causses Error when trying to load

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pickle, numpy-ndarray

Edit : For those looking for answers, my file was corrupted hpauli suggested,  knowing the shape the array should have, I opened the file using open(filenam) as append mode and appended 0 until there was a correct amount of data, then I split the files in 2 and loaded the first part, then splitted the second half and splitted itself into 2 more parts, etc... until I had recovered most of my data.

I'm making an ai using image recognition, so I recorded each frames of me playing into a numpy array. It worked just fine when the first time I exported all the images and got the 6 thousand of them. Now, I was recording a lot more data but suddently I get this erro with no change in my code or environement

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "D:\Dev\Fall-Guys-AI-Race\utils\CreateImages.py", line 6, in 
> >
> data = np.load("D:/Dev/Fall-Guys-AI-Race/data/training_data.npy", allow_pickle=True)
>
> File "D:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 430, in load
> >
> return format.read_array(fid, allow_pickle=allow_pickle,
>
> File "D:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py", line 786, in read_array
> >
> array.shape = shape
>
> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2147483648 into shape (14460,224,224,3)

Here is my CreateImages.py :

```
import cv2, os
import numpy as np

listing = os.listdir("D:/Dev/Fall-Guys-AI-Race/data/")
for j in range(1):
    data = np.load("D:/Dev/Fall-Guys-AI-Race/data/training_data.npy", allow_pickle=True)
    targets = np.load("D:/Dev/Fall-Guys-AI-Race/data/target_data.npy", allow_pickle=True)

    print(f'Image Data Shape: {data.shape}')
    print(f'targets Shape: {targets.shape}')

    # Lets see how many of each type of move we have.
    unique_elements, counts = np.unique(targets, return_counts=True)

    # Store both data and targets in a list.
    # We may want to shuffle down the road.

    holder_list = []
    for i, image in enumerate(data):
        holder_list.append([data[i], targets[i]])

    count_up = 0
    count_left = 0
    count_right = 0
    count_jump = 0
    count_down = 0

    for data in holder_list:
        #writes data to image in correct folder, skipped because lots of lines:
        cv2.imwrite(f"*my_path*{count_left}.png", data[0])
    print("done")
    print(count_down, count_up, count_jump, count_left, count_right)
```

Thanks for the help

Edit: I cant even load the array (which is stored as a file) so i don't think I can modify it

Comment: There's a problem with the file - it appears to have lost some bytes.  The shape, specified in the file header, assumes there are `2176634880` data elements (float?).  That's larger than the size specified in the error.  The file is corrupted in some way.

Comment: @hpaulj It's also interesting that the size reported in the error is exactly 2^31.

Comment: @DanMašek, which is the upper limit of 'int32'.  But I'm not aware of limits on the size of arrays that `np.save/load` can handle.

Comment: Yeah, I retested and it seems that the limit on the size of arrays is the int32 limit